# how to find to total price of an item after a reduction with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, percentage, calculation

i am trying to get the total price of an item after a reduction has been applied. So far I am able to find the amount of the reduction but I cannot manage to display the total price after the reduction is applied

```
        var price = document.getElementById("price");
        var reduction = document.getElementById("reduction");
        var newPrice = document.getElementById("newPrice");
        var priceToPay = document.getElementById("priceToPay");

        price.addEventListener("keyup",myAnswer);
        reduction.addEventListener("keyup",myAnswer);
        priceToPay.addEventListener("change" ,myAnswer);
        newPrice.addEventListener("change",myAnswer);


        function myAnswer ()

        {   // this part is used to display the value of the discount
            newPrice.value = (Number(reduction.value) * Number(price.value)) / 100 + " £";
        }

         {

// this part does not work, but essentially is normally used to  give me the total price of the item after the reduction has been applied.

             priceToPay.value = Number(price.value) - Number(newPrice.value) + " £";
         }
```

if the percentage of reduction is 35% and the item normally cost $154 ,following the first calculation in the function Myanswer  the result is $53.9 .With the second calculation The item should be now priced at $100.1   ( original price - reduction)

Comment: `newPrice.value` isn't numeric due to the `" £"` symbol. Store some numeric variables

Comment: you are totally right, by taking off the sign "£" the whole thing work. Thank you